# I need help in c++ change cases

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, uppercase, letter

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence =""; 
    cin >> sentence; //aab
    int i;
    
    for (i=0;i=sentence.length();i++){ 
        if (i<=65 && i>=90) {
            sentence = sentence[i] + 32;
        }
        else if (i<=97 && i>=122){                //i=0,
            sentence = sentence [i]-32;
        }
        
        
    }

    cout << sentence;
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter this code for changing cases of letters it keeps asking me to enter more although I have only one cin in the code why does that happen?

Comment: `cin >> sentence; //aab` is a bug if you expect a sentence to have spaces in it. Its a bug because this statement will read up to the first whitespace character, ignoring the rest of the line that was typed.

Comment: `string sentence ="";`  the `= ""` part is unnecessary. `string sentence;` is sufficient.

Comment: Unrelated, but use `std::islower`/`std::isupper` and `std::tolower`/`std::toupper` instead of magic numbers.

Comment: [Edit] and show an example of input along with expected vs. actual output.

Comment: There are no numbers that are both `<=65` *and* `>=90`, or both `<=97` *and* `>=122`. You meant `>= 65`, `<= 90`, `>= 97`, and `<= 122`. (Do you see how helpful `std::isupper` and `std::islower` are?)

Comment: Btw. in your `if` statements, you're checking the index `i` while you surely want to check the contents of `sentence` at index `i`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Or  `65 <= character && character <= 90` and `97 <= character && character <= 122`, which I find more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Problem one is inadvertent assignment. Look at your loop condition:

```
for (i=0;i=sentence.length();i++)
```

That assigns `i` rather than comparing it, resulting in an infinite loop. Use `<` instead of `=`:

```
for (i=0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
```

Problem two is you're comparing the position in the string to the character ranges rather than the character itself, and the comparison is backwards and can never be true:

```
if (i<=65 && i>=90)
```

Should be:

```
if (sentence[i] >= 65 && sentence[i] <= 90)
```

Same for the lower case range.

Finally, you don't want to change the whole sentence to one character, just that character:

```
sentence = sentence[i] + 32;
```

Should be:

```
sentence[i] = sentence[i] + 32;
```

Again, same for the lower case range.

With these changes, it seems to work, at least for single words. If you want to do entire sentences, I'd recommend using [`std::getline(std::cin, sentence);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) rather than `cin >> sentence;`.